# path issue in File connection manager SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am executing a parent package which will excute the child packages. In the parent package I have established connection to child packages using file connection manager. It works fine in my loacl machine. When I move to development server, it is throwing error that it couldn't find the child package. Actually it resides in the same folder. What path should I give in the file connection manager ? any ideas to get rid of this issue ?
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2):

It uses an absolute path, even if you've entered it as a relative path. It won't do any searching or hunting for the .dtsx.

When you create the package ensure that you enable "Package Configuration", thus when you deploy you can override package settings like this one on the server. You'll also find that you can use this to modify database connection strings, passwords, etc.

Some articles with more details:

- http://www.sqlis.com/post/Easy-Package-Configuration.aspx
- http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1405

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Package Configuration to use the relative paths as explained in the following link:

[Relative Paths in SSIS](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15)

and for fixing the bug in the relative path for the Configuration file, do the following:

[Fix Relative Paths](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Fix%20Relative%20Paths&referringTitle=Home)